# Concatenate 2 Angular NGRX Actions inside an Effect

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am very new to redux and I am facing a problem that I don't know if it is even possible to solve or I should change how the component and store works.

I have a button that, when clicked, dispatches this action:

```
export const updateOrganizationSettings = createAction(
  '[Organization settings effect] Update organization settings via service',
  props<{ organizationSettings: OrganizationSettings }>()
);
```

This action triggers the following effect:

```
updateOrganizationSettings$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(organizationSettingsActionTypes.updateOrganizationSettings),
        concatMap((action) =>
          this.organizationSettingsService.updateOrganizationSettings(
            action.organizationSettings
          )
        )
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

It calls an API that, on success, returns true.

What I want to do is somehow dispatch on success another Action that then changes the store:

```
export const organizationSettingsUpdated = createAction(
  '[Organization settings reducer] Organization settings updated successfully',
  props<{ updatedOrganizationSettings: OrganizationSettings }>()
);
```

The problem is that the response from the API is true/false while this action needs the updated model which I have only for the first action.

Is there a way to do it? Is this a bad way to work with the store?
I can as a last option change the APIs to return the updated model but I'd like to know if there are other possibilities.

Thanks

=== EDIT ===

This is the API service calling the backend inside the effect:

```
updateOrganizationSettings(
    organizationSettings: OrganizationSettings
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.httpService
      .put<boolean>('/general-settings', organizationSettings)
      .then((data) => data);
  }
```

This should be the action that gets dispatched after the api call returns true:

```
export const organizationSettingsUpdated = createAction(
  '[Organization settings reducer] Organization settings updated successfully',
  props<{ updatedOrganizationSettings: OrganizationSettings }>()
);
```

And finally this should be the reducer

```
on(
    organizationSettingsActionTypes.organizationSettingsUpdated,
    (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      organizationSettings: action.updatedOrganizationSettings
    })
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
updateOrganizationSettings$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(organizationSettingsActionTypes.updateOrganizationSettings),
      mergeMap((action) => {
        return this.organizationSettingsService.updateOrganizationSettings(action.organizationSettings).pipe(
          map(response => updateOrganizationSettingsSuccess(response)) --> the action you are asking for
          catchError(error => updateOrganizationSettingsError(error))
       )
    })
));
```

Ofcourse you should create a `updateOrganizationSettingsSuccess` and `updateOrganizationSettingsError` action + hooking it to a reducer.

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jeroen.
I can see how this could help but it is not exactly (I think) the answer i was looking for.
I am going to update the original question with the code of the API service call and the followup action and reducer!

Comment: I think Jeroen has the right answer, the only that you would want to change for your case is to pass in the payload of your input action to your output action
```
 return this.organizationSettingsService.updateOrganizationSettings(action.organizationSettings).pipe(
          map(response => organizationSettingsUpdated(action.payload)) 
          catchError(error => updateOrganizationSettingsError(error))

```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Jeroen answer was the one i needed. It wasn't working because i couldn't just pipe after the service because it returned a Promise. I used from() operator and then used pipe.